# Simpl asp.net form as part of email

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to send a simple form with few fields as part of newsletter which users can fill in their email client let us say, gmail, outlook and then the details should be save in the database.
Form fields.

```
Name:
Tel:
Mailing address:
Email:

Submit Button
```

Once they click the submit button can i somehow save this information in database which. let us say form is submitted to www.website.com/saveEmailForm.aspx

Comment: Forms are not widely supported by email clients, so yes you could send one, but you may never get the data back

Comment: Check this link, for supported mail clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/ . If it's fine for you, yes you can use it

Answer (score 1):

Its possible, but your results are going to vary widely depending on the email client. IMO, much better to provide a link to the form on your website for a consistent experience.

http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/